# How to visualize proximity score in Random Forests

Tags: data-visualization, random-forest, ensemble-learning, multidimensional-scaling

For a Random Forest, we can construct a **`N x N`**  (where **`N`** is the number of data points) proximity matrix **`P`** where **`P[i,j]`** is how "close" the **`i-th`** data point is from the **`j-th`** data point. In [Gilles Loupes' PhD dissertation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.7502.pdf), he shows an example of a very beautiful proximity visualization using the MNIST dataset:
[image]

My question is - how are these proximity plots made? Is there any intuitive difference between that and your traditional distance/similarity matrices? For example, if I have **`N = 500`** data points, should I run the proximity matrix through some sort of dimensionality reduction technique like PCA / SVD / t-SNE so it is of form **`500 x 2`**, and the visualize it?

Comment: Is there no description of how the plot was constructed in the text of the dissertation that you cite?

Comment: There is not.@Sycorax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few lines later in the dissertation, the author writes

> Figure 4.6 represents the proximity matrix learned for a 10-class handwritten digit classification task, as projected on a plane using Multidimensional Scaling [Kruskal, 1964].

In addition to the citation the author provides, you can find more information about [multidimensional-scaling](/questions/tagged/multidimensional-scaling) by searching for posts bearing the tag.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I did not see this when I was perusing the paper.